# Making navbar sticky makes dropdown-content dissapear

Tags: html, css

I made a navbar for a project of mine. I am trying to make it sticky, but when I do that the dropdown-content of the button dissapears.

I would like to stay with only css and html, but if it requires some javascript that's fine too (javascript frameworks please only if you don't know the native javascript code).

To make it sticky I added `position: sticky; top: 0; z-index: 1;` to `nav`.

```css
nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F05;
        /* horizontally center */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
}
nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    float: left;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav div {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
nav div button {
    line-height: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #000;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
}
nav a:hover, nav div button:hover {
    background-color: #d40037;
}
nav div div {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(212,0,57,0.5);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #303030;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d40037;
    border-right: 1px solid #d40037;
    border-left: 1px solid #d40037;
    min-width: 160px;
    z-index: 1;
}
nav div div a {
    font-weight: normal;
    float: none;
    color: #DDD;
    padding: 12px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}
nav div div a:hover {
    background-color: #1E1E1E;
}
nav div:hover > div {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>HTML und CSS | Grundlagen</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
   <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
</head>
<body>

   <header>Grundlagen</header>

   <nav>
      <a href="index.html">Index</a>
      <div>
         <button>Wissenschaften</button>
         <div>
            <a href="mathe.html">Mathe</a>
            <a href="physik.html">Physik</a>
            <a href="chemie.html">Chemie</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button>Sprachen</button>
         <div>
            <a href="deutsch.html">Deutsch</a>
            <a href="englisch.html">Englisch</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button>IT</button>
         <div>
            <a href="csharp.html">C#</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)">HTML und CSS</a>
            <a href="netzwerktechnik.html">Netzwerktechnik</a>
            <a href="elektrotechnik.html">Elektrotechnik</a>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div>
         <button>Sonstige Fächer</button>
         <div>
            <a href="geografie.html">Geografie</a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </nav>

   <main>

   ...

   </main>

   <a href="#"><footer>Top</footer></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use classes, it is much easier. I suppose the problem is with `nav div div` and `position:absolute`. There is no position relative in your nav so the position will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the overflow: hidden. I removed in here:

```
nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #F05;
        /* horizontally center */
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You first parent element of `<nav>` should have a position relative, because that element automatically becomes an container to element with a position sticky. In this case the first parent are `<body>`

So you have add some code to body:

```
body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You're not positioning your `div div` dropdown menu (with `top, bottom, left, right`), hence it stays in place (below the button), but is taken out of the flow, meaning it will not reserve space in it's parent `<div>`.

Your parent `<div>` for the dropdown is using `overflow: hidden`, which cuts off the dropdown menu, even when it's visible.

Since the menu is not reserving space, **you should be fine removing `overflow: hidden` from it's parent**.

Are you aware of your *containing block* for the `position: absolute`?
Absolute positioning is actually relative to a *positioned parent*. That is the first parent element that has a `position` other than `static`. See [Types of positioning](https://uaie)

In your case, that would be the *sticky* `<nav>`. If you would use positioning `top` f.e., these coordinates would be relative to the top left corner of `<nav>`.